# How to build Charts in Pentaho? using xAction or using CDF?

Tags: dashboard, pentaho, xaction

After lot of struggle and googling finally I have managed to develop one dashboard using Pentaho CDE. While googling I found out that many people use xAction files to create charts and then embed those files in dashboard.

So I would like to know which way is better in terms of maintenance, performance?
  1) Using only Pentaho CDE or 
  2) Creating charts in xAction and then embedding those charts

What do usually people do to develop dashboards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

xActions are pretty much deprecated and are dying a slow painful death. However CDE is new and actively updated technology that is of the moment.

So CDE, all the way.

Perhaps you should blog your experiences - there are other blogs out there about using CDE and it is very easy to get started, so it would be interesting to know your specific troubles.

Comment: Hi Codek, thanks a lot for your all the answers. I think you have answered my most of the questions related to Pentaho. I have one query about Pentaho CDE. There are lot of third party charting api's available like HighCharts or ExtJs charts by Sencha. So can we use Pentaho as backend for querying and build charts using these third party api's? If yes, how? Right now only way I know to do this is by using design studio and writting javascript actions in it. Also I would like to know how to integrate dashboard files in my existing web app?

Comment: In theory you could do that by creating a custom component in CDF and then using CDA to provide the data.  I dont know exactly how that is done though.

Comment: Thanks Codek. I will search how this can be done and maybe i'll write one tutorial on it :)

Comment: Hi Shekhar, Did you got solutions? Do you got any solution to integrate the third party charts with pentaho? I am trying to integrate the HighCharts with the pentaho.

Comment: @srahul07, I have found out that creating xActions is the easiest way to integrate Pentaho with third party APIs. Currently I am using this approach only to integrate with ExtJs. Also I am trying to know how to write new BI plugin. I have stopped playing with CDE because of two reasons. First reason is, there's not much documentation available about it and the charts/graphs it draws are not so great if we compare them with what is offered by ExtJs or dojo or Highcharts. Second reason is lack of documentation, tutorials, examples, books. Some tutorials are there but we have to pay for them.

Comment: @Shekhar, Thanks. I do believe in xAction for my purpose. In my case I am also using xaction to give mdx query to generate a result which I would like to plot in graph. The mdx query is generated by another xaction from the parameters received in service request, mdx is really simple. I am thinking porting this mdx query generation from xaction to independent php engine (looking for any existing, if not then build own). then use this mdx query in xaction to generate report and pass it to the third party charts.    Also, ext js 4 also looks good. will give it a try as well.

Comment: @Codek : hey can u plz provide any link , how to use xaction in cde dashboard , actually i have an xaction , but i can display it in my CDE dashboard , any help plz

Answer (score 0):

I think CDE dashboard better with the flash report